# Host firewall blocks IP when using SSE based chat system

Tags: php, ip, firewall, server-sent-events

I have implemented a chat system using Server-Sent Events (SSE) and PHP.
The retry time in the server is 1 second and the client uses jQuery, Ajax and HTML5.
I have two places on my website that use eventsource :

- First, my home page that shows number of messages received, and would change if a message comes now.
- Second, the chat page that shows chat content and messages.

As I mentioned, every second the server php file runs and send a message to the client (new chat entry or empty message).
The problem is that my host firewall blocks my IP when browsing home page (and not even chat page) after some minutes.
The CT_LIMIT of the firewall is 150 requests per 30 seconds.
What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Add an exception to your firewall or raise the retry time?

Comment: That wouldn't be a solution since many users may use this chat system from different IPs, I raised the retry time to 3 seconds and the problem still exists, raising more may dissatisfy users about chatting.